# Rails Route - specific URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to implement a tracking pixel for inside an email.

The tracking pixel URL should look something like this:

```
http://example.com/__track.gif?id=XXXXXXX&u=XXXXX
```

Questions:

1. How do I create a route specifically for that?
2. while it says it's .gif, I don't actually want a gif file, as I want a rails controller to get called and be able to run a few methods when called, using the url params.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your routes.rb file:

```
match "/_track.gif" => "controller_name#action_name"
```

Replacing `controller_name` & `action_name` with those appropriate.

I recommend you read over the [Rails Guide for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), as `match` is noted in the very first section.